# Add CSS file to Spring Boot + Spring Security Thymeleaf file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, stylesheet, thymeleaf

I wanted to add CSS file to my HTML file. 
The problem appeared when I tried to add CSS to Spring Security application (I work on basic Spring Getting Started Content). I blame Spring Security because without it the CSS file loads properly.

`Application.java` file:

```java
package mainpack;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

`MvcConfig.java` file:

```java
package mainpack;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/register").setViewName("register");
        registry.addViewController("/whatever").setViewName("whatever");
    }
}
```

`WebSecurityConfig.java` file:

```java
package mainpack;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/index", "/register", "../static/css", "../static/images").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

I load CSS with line:

```xml
<link href="../static/css/index.css" th:href="@{/css/index.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in `index.html` file.

Comment: Please add your project structure. It will help others. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your pattern `../static/css` is not matching your relative URL `../static/css/index.css`, see [AntPathMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html):

> `PathMatcher` implementation for Ant-style path patterns.
>
> Part of this mapping code has been kindly borrowed from Apache Ant.
>
> The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:
>
> - `?` matches one character
> - `*` matches zero or more characters
> - `**` matches zero or more directories in a path
> - `{spring:[a-z]+}` matches the regexp `[a-z]+` as a path variable named "spring"

and [Spring Boot Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content):

> By default, resources are mapped on `/**` but you can tune that via `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern`.

Your request will be redirected to login form, because your are not logged in and all other requests need authentication.

To fix it, change your pattern to `/css/**` and `/images/**`.

A better solution for static resources is [WebSecurity#ignoring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#ignoring--):

> Allows adding `RequestMatcher` instances that Spring Security should ignore. Web Security provided by Spring Security (including the `SecurityContext`) will not be available on `HttpServletRequest` that match. Typically the requests that are registered should be that of only static resources. For requests that are dynamic, consider mapping the request to allow all users instead.
>
> Example Usage:
>
> ```java
>  webSecurityBuilder.ignoring()
>  // ignore all URLs that start with /resources/ or /static/
>                 .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**");
> ```

Comment: This is the code snippet that works for me for sub folders too. Thanks @Dur
 http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll();

Answer (score 5):

The `web.ignore()`worked the best for me. just add the following method to your `WebSecurityConfig` class.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/icon/**");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.antMatchers("/**/*.js", "/**/*.css").permitAll();
```

This allows all the js and css files present in resources/static folder to be permitted for request access.

Comment: Thank you very much. I searched about this question several days and finally find the best solution!