# CSS/JS not working in HTML, Error : MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: spring-boot, mime-types

I am working on basic spring boot application which has Spring security enabled.
When I try to use CSS in my thymeleaf HTML, I get the below error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:9999/login' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring Boot, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52124687/1470607) explains one of the more common sources of this problem. For other people to be able to help you, you'll need to provide more details about your specific setup. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for quick response . i appreciate it .

Comment: My issue resolved from below link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910004/add-css-file-to-spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-file

Answer (score 2):

[Add CSS file to Spring Boot + Spring Security Thymeleaf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910004/add-css-file-to-spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-file)         This will resolve the issue , when working with spring security we need to permit folder access as mentioned here.